Getting IOException - "The semaphore timeout period has expired" while using Apache Mina SshClient
We are using Apache Mina to connect to an RHEL server, and intermittently we are getting IOException - "The semaphore timeout period has expired" while using Apache Mina SshClient.
This error only occurs when connecting from a Windows client. Below is the stack trace.
2024-08-07 13:09:25,424 DEBUG [sshd-SshClient[569b3009]-timer-thread-1] o.a.s.c.i.n.Nio2Session writeBuffer(Nio2Session[local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:64688, remote=vmr-iod-1001.ete.ka.sw.ericsson.se/10.223.58.242:22]) writing 60 bytes
2024-08-07 13:09:25,574 DEBUG [sshd-SshClient[569b3009]-nio2-thread-5] o.a.s.c.i.n.Nio2Session handleReadCycleFailure(Nio2Session[local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:64688, remote=vmr-iod-1001.ete.ka.sw.ericsson.se/10.223.58.242:22]) IOException after 19180462400 nanos at read cycle=34: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

2024-08-07 13:09:25,574 DEBUG [sshd-SshClient[569b3009]-nio2-thread-5] o.a.s.c.i.n.Nio2Session exceptionCaught(Nio2Session[local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:64688, remote=vmr-iod-1001.ete.ka.sw.ericsson.se/10.223.58.242:22]) caught IOException[The semaphore timeout period has expired.
] - calling handler
2024-08-07 13:09:25,574 DEBUG [sshd-SshClient[569b3009]-nio2-thread-5] o.a.s.c.s.ClientSessionImpl signalAuthFailure(ClientSessionImpl[installadmin@vmr-iod-1001.ete.ka.sw.ericsson.se/10.223.58.242:22]) type=IOException, signalled=false, first=false: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

2024-08-07 13:09:25,574 WARN [sshd-SshClient[569b3009]-nio2-thread-5] o.a.s.c.s.ClientSessionImpl exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[installadmin@vmr-iod-1001.ete.ka.sw.ericsson.se/10.223.58.242:22])[state=Opened] IOException: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

java.io.IOException: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.translateErrorToIOException(Iocp.java:309)
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$700(Iocp.java:46)
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:399)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

We are trying to execute commands on the remote server using ChannelExec::open method. Error only occurs 3 in 10 times.
